# blocking multiple ip to access my server in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, blocking, lighttpd

I need help for blocking multiple ip 
actually from last 8-10 days multiple ip hitting my server from susapi.lenovomm.com domain continously 
so want to block this

Details of servers and services

Server Linux on EC2
Lighttpd
LB(load balancer in AWS)

In aws they are not providing facilities to block ip before hitting the LB so we can't block the ip before the LB
and in LB security group also we can't block IPs in the security group

So following things i tried

Attempt 1 – Throght Lighttpd configuration

I added a module "mod_extforward" in lighttpd

then added " extforward.forwarder = ("myip" => "trust")"
to lighttpd.conf

and added this for blocking such IP's

$HTTP["remoteip"] =~ "203.82.66.237|203.82.66.231|203.82.66.239|203.82.66.230|203.82.66.233|203.82.66.235|203.82.66.238|203.82.66.228|" {
       url.access-deny = ( "" )
  }

Attempt 2 – Blocking IP's throught IP tables firewall i blocked but its not working

/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 203.82.66.237 -j DROP

Attempt 3 – Blocking IP's throught IP route add i blocked but its not working

/sbin/route add -host 203.82.66.239 reject

Can anyone help me on this how to block this IP access in my server

Regards
Nitesh
nitesh.gupta01@yahoo.in

Comment: Can you elaborate on: `LB security group also we can't block IPs in the security group` Security groups are exactly for that. Are you sure the security group rules are correct?

Comment: @helloV security groups are designed to explicitly "allow," so it's tricky to allow 0.0.0.0/0 with exceptions at that layer.  Network ACLs in VPC on the ELB's subnet would do the trick, though. NiteshKumarGupta are you using VPC or EC2-classic?

Comment: Thanks all for your reply

Comment: I am using VPC in aws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **[Network Access Control List (NACL)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html)** on the VPC subnet(s) where your Elastic Load Balancer is located.

While Security Group are associated with Amazon EC2 instances and define "Allow" ranges, NACLs are associated with subnets and define both "Allow" and "Deny" permissions.

You can then provide a CIDR range of IP addresses that you wish to block, and the traffic will never hit the Load Balancer.